# how to call function in component after change value in store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a store with some values and two components.
First component its range slider and second its component when i need to call function after **red value** is changed.

In first component i change slider value and add that in vuex store.

```
state: {
    value: 0,
      rgbColors: {
        red: 0
      }
  },
```

How i understand i need to use `store.subscribe.watch.rgbColors.red` or `store.watch.rgbColors.red`, its is correct?

And if its correct how call some functions after change value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`store.subscribe` subscribes to mutators. Ala: If you call `this.$store.commit('myMutator', payload)`, your subscriber function would be called with `myMutator` and `payload`. This is not what you want.

`store.watch` will watch some part of the state you define, but its main downside is that you do need to unwatch manually. I believe you would use it like this:

```
const unWatchFn = store.watch(
  (state) => state.rgbColors.red,
  (newRed) => {
    console.log(newRed)
  }
);

// And sometime later
unWatchFn()
```

---

You usually don't want to use actual watchers in Vue, because calculating things via computed properties automatically keeps the calculated variable up-to-date. If you need to use watchers, use them on actual components so they automatically get removed and do not cause a memory leak or weird errors. In either case, you will need to make a getter in your store module. Afterwards make either a computed property or a watcher in your component on this getter.

```
// store.js
export default {
  state: {
    rgbColors: {
      red: 0,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0
    }
  },

  getters: {
    color(state) {
      return state.rgbColors;
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    setColor(state, { red, green, blue }) {
      state.rgbColors.red = red;
      state.rgbColors.green = green;
      state.rgbColors.blue = blue;
    }
  }
};
```

```
// SomeComponent.vue
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "App",

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["color"]),

    styling() {
      const { red, green, blue } = this.color;

      return {
        "background-color": `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`
      };
    }
  },

  watch: {
    color: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newColor) {
        console.log("Oh, look, a new color!", newColor);
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setColor(red, green, blue) {
      this.$store.commit("setColor", {
        red,
        green,
        blue
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Can you @Sumurai8 explain this please ` ...mapGetters(["color"]),`

Comment: @DarckBlezzer mapGetters is something from vuex. It works the same as `color() { return this.$store.getters.color; }`. See [the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) for more information. The `...` before `mapGetters` destructures the object that returns from `mapGetters` so we can use the keys and values from that `mapGetters` call in the `computed` object.